# How can I state Ranges where part of each range is a dynamic variable in a different workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

Somehow, the statement that I am trying to perfect below works sometimes and then fails to work with the

> Range of Object Worksheet Failed

message.

Here is the code in its simplest form so that you can see what I am trying to do. In case it matters, my plan is to call this macro at the end of the source workbook Sheet 1 Print code, thus automating what is currently a manual process for users.

```
Public Sub CopyExportToTracking()

    Dim kng As Range
 
    Set kng = Sheet4.Range("$A$1:$K$ & Range("M1")")
    
    kng.Copy
    
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Michelle\Documents\Maple Inventory System\YYYY\YYYY SYRUP MANAGEMENT\test YYYY SYRUP INVENTORY TRACKING.xlsm")
    
    Dim vng As Range
    
    Set vng = Sheet8.Range("$B$" & Range("Y1"))
    
    vng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("Y1")` is unqualified, so it assumes `ActiveSheet` - Use this instead : `Sheet4.Range("Y1")` - It does not automatically assume you are referring to the same sheet from the beginning of the line.

Comment: Do you have two `Sheet4` worksheets, in different workbooks?

Comment: Duhhh!  First reference (Sheet 4) is to active source workbook where new information is being created.  Second reference (Sheet 8) is to an inventory tracking workbook where information is to be posted with each new Sale (sheet 4 belongs to the Sold Template).

Comment: Referencing the codename like that only works for sheets in the workbook where the code is running.

Comment: Both `Range("$A$1:$K$ & Range("M1")")` and `Range("$B$" & Range("Y1"))` are invalid range references.

Comment: I can get the other workbook to cooperate with no problem, but does anyone know if a range be written with a cell reference as the final piece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have started recorded the original macro from the default main sheets of the source and the tracking workbooks.  My error was in having the source sheet open instead of the usual landing sheet and the the other workbook sheet I would write to previously closed on that sheet, so I had not recorded the navigation to those sheets.  Also, I have added a Workbook_Open code to the other workbook so that it has a "normal" landing sheet when it opens.  Ugly, but no one else will ever see it.  Thank you all for your help.

```
Sheets("Export Table").Select
Range("$A$1:$K$" & Range("M1")).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Michelle\Documents\Maple Inventory System\YYYY\YYYY SYRUP 
MANAGEMENT\test YYYY SYRUP INVENTORY TRACKING.xlsm"
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=5
Sheets("Sales").Select
Range("$B$" & (1 + Range("Y1"))).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming vng is in the workbook you just opened. Try fully qualifying the range. I've also fixed a couple of syntax errors and used a sheet name reference (which you'll need to change).

```vb
Public Sub CopyExportToTracking()

    Dim kng As Range
 
    With Sheet4
        Set kng = .Range("$A$1:$K$" & .Range("M1"))
    End With

    kng.Copy
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Michelle\Documents\Maple Inventory System\YYYY\YYYY SYRUP MANAGEMENT\test YYYY SYRUP INVENTORY TRACKING.xlsm")
    
    Dim vng As Range
    
    
    Set vng = wb.Seets("Sheet8").Range("$B$" & Sheet4.Range("Y1"))
    
    vng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
End Sub
```

This assumes there's some numbers in M1 and Y1 on Sheet4 in your source workbook.

Comment: SSlinky:  Your code seems happy except for an expected end of statement on Set wb line that I'm not able to fix.  Can you please help again with that?

Comment: Put parenthesis around what it's opening.... `Workbooks.Open("..etc..")`

Comment: @braX Good pick up. I'd removed them and then added the variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're trying to use the worksheet codename to refer to sheets in your Tracker, but if you are you could use the approach below.

```vb
Public Sub CopyExportToTracking()

    Dim wbTracker As Workbook
 
    'You should consider giving your worksheet meaningful
    '  CodeNames such as (eg) "SoldItems"
    Sheet4.Range("$A$1:$K$" & Sheet4.Range("M1").value).copy
    
    Set wbTracker = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Michelle\Documents\Maple Inventory System\" & _
                      "YYYY\YYYY SYRUP MANAGEMENT\test YYYY SYRUP INVENTORY TRACKING.xlsm")
    
    'Paste to sheet in tracker identified by its CodeName
    SheetByCodename(wbTracker, "Sheet8").Range("$B$" & Sheet4.Range("Y1").value) _
                           .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wbTracker.Save
    
End Sub

'return a worksheet from workbook `wb` whose codeName matches `codeName`
Function SheetByCodename(wb As Workbook, codeName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.codeName = codeName Then
            Set SheetByCodename = ws
            Exit Function 'done
        End If
    Next ws
    'if we got here the function returns `Nothing`
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry to say that I tried to manage the SheetbyCodeName and did try to figure that out without success.  Thank you kindly for your efforts.